# How to add correct 301 redirect to specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am searching for the correct code to add in the htaccess file for this situation:

At springintveld.nl there was an old Joomla!site. That site is deleted. The domain is moved and set as Domainpointer in Direct Admin of kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl
For the organisation Spring in t Veld, I have created a special part in the menu of kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl
So when a visitor is browsing to springintveld.nl, he must be redirected to : kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl/peuteropvang

I hoped it could work with this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^springintveld.nl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.springintveld.nl$
RewriteRule ^/?$ “http://www.kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl/peuteropvang” [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But with this code the redirection is still to the mailpage of kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl

I hope someone can help to give me the correct code.

Comment: `the redirection is still to the mailpage` What do mean? Where is it going now? Also did you turn on the rewriteengine `RewriteEngine on` needs to be above the rewritecond.

Comment: The redirection is now to the mainpage.
What I mean is: The visitor is redirected to: kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl and not to: kindcentrumschalkhaar.nl/peuteropvang
And dat is what I need.
Yes, RewriteEngine is ON.and the rewritecode is at the end of my htaccess now.